# A program like Skype with auto answer for iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, skype

I have build a robot with a head actually made of an iPod (with iOS 6). I would like to take control of the camera remotely so I can control the robot from afar.

The program I need is very much like Skype, but I need to automatically activate the call as the robot is unattended.

- The camera should not be activated all the time.
- Unlike most camera programs, it has to be like a Skype call (video and sound both ways).

Skype allows you to do that but only on desktop version!

I have searched for such a program/functionality and didn't find anything. I am actually thinking of adding one servomotor to answer the calls on the screen... ridiculous.

Ideally this program should work on my iPod with iOS 6 but a solution on iOS 8 or even Android interests me as well as a backup solution.

Any idea?

Comment: i found another program that do almost everything but still not everything:

Answer (score 1):

So I found another program that does almost everything and that is "usable" in my case, as Skype is not.

[Babyphone 3g](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/babyphone-3g-babymonitor/id1264053829?mt=8)

Pros:

1. It has the auto answer feature.
2. The camera can be turned off when not used.
3. If the connection is bad, it offers to take pictures.

Cons:

1. Video is only one way (big down) but sound can be both ways.
2. The "babything" design which makes it look unapropriate for me when it is the best I found.
3. Not free (and probably pay for each separate device you want to connect, have to check that)

I am not sure I should answer my question or edit my question in that case...